# "know 'the why' of" something

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality

Is this sentence grammatically correct. I am particularly concerned about ***the why*** part:

> As mentioned earlier, the goal is not always 100% clear but it is important to know ***'the why'*** of wanting it.

Comment: It's not "grammatical" - that's why '**the why**' is in *scare quotes*. In your specific context, I don't really see why the writer didn't just use the natural construction *it's important to know **why** we want it,* but the meaning is obvious even with the "non-grammatical" version as cited.

Comment: Your edit invalidated my comment, but whether and where any scare quotes might appear doesn't affect the basic syntax issue.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I just corrected the scare quotes.

Comment: @FumbleFingers BTW, what about "why" as a noun? Is it only used in the phrase "‘the whys and wherefores"? Or should be always plural?

Comment: At a certain level I think it becomes a pointless exercise to ask whether some [particular usage represents a "noun" or whatever. Consider, for example, *I understand how. I just don't understand why*. If ***how*** and ***why*** aren't nouns there, do they suddenly become so in *I understand the how. I just don't understand the why* (which is by no means an uncommon construction)? But usages like this don't exactly reflect standard grammar, so whereas it's fine for advanced learners to be aware that such forms *are* used, for people wanting to learn basic "grammar", they're just a distraction.

Comment: FumbleFingers, thank you for your comment and time. I appreciate your help. It is true that, I wanted to learn the basic grammar (English is not my first language and I often struggle with basic sentences). However, this does not mean that I am not interested in the more advanced versions. In fact, I am grateful to all those, who took time to provide such detailed explanations. Strangely, the version of advanced learners felt more natural to me than the basic 'grammar' you are writing about. Thank you :)

Comment: So, you want to learn the ins and outs of English grammar.

Answer (score 2):

It is correct, and it's a construction that is used frequently.  The scare quotes are not strictly necessary in this sentence, but they are not infrequently used, either.  You will even find occasional use of double-quotes.

Saying *the why* or *the what* or *the where* is an idiomatic way of suggesting the *type* of questioning needed.  You can think of *the why* as being roughly synonymous with "the answers to *why* questions", and as you can see below, if you want to add a subject afterwards, you use the preposition "of":

[Why the 'Why' of the Sale Matters More Than the 'What'](https://www.entrepreneur.com/article/245082)

The BBC's Show [The Why Factor](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/p00xtky9)

[The Why, What, and How of Management Innovation](https://hbr.org/2006/02/the-why-what-and-how-of-management-innovation)

And here is a particularly fun one that's a little hard to decode:

[The Why Behind the How and the What of Content Strategy](https://www.acrolinx.com/blog/behind-content-strategy/)

US News & World Report: [Revisiting the Why of Watergate](https://www.usnews.com/opinion/blogs/peter-roff/2014/08/11/figuring-out-the-why-of-richard-nixons-watergate-scandal)

The NIH study [Weight isn't selling: The insidious effects of weight stigmatization in retail settings](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25751751): *"Second, we examine the "why" of weight-based stigmatization and find that weight-related negative stereotypes compound to produce indirect but strong effects of stigmatization in retail settings (Study 2)"*